# Originate smart contract with empty arguments

Tags: smart-contracts, origination

I try to initialize a smart contract with five arguments being nat * timestamp * nat * timestamp * address.  However, I only want to fill the last argument with some value but for the first four I try to fill nil.  But I cannot get myself right on the format.  Any one may help on this?  Many thanks.

I tried below code,

```
./tezos-client originate contract oracle_test00 transferring 0 from alice running oracle.tz --init 'Pair (Pair (Pair nil nil) nil nil) "tz1PKKC9NTsxxfwYpg1bVAY5k5AKuPYe9gpg"'
```

or

```
./tezos-client originate contract oracle_test00 transferring 0 from alice running oracle.tz --init 'Pair (Pair (Pair "" "") "" "") "tz1PKKC9NTsxxfwYpg1bVAY5k5AKuPYe9gpg"'
```

Both are wrong.

Answer (score 2):

There is no `nil` on tezos. You will need to use the [option](https://tezos.gitlab.io/michelson-reference/#type-option) type, which can be `None` or `Some <value>`.

[A SmartPy example](https://smartpy.io/ide?cid=QmZEEwbb7eEAvB5fErzUd3GnUcJajVsHjAyN19KsVEQ7fp&k=a34f48202f1f84e0afad)

[image]

Comment: Thank you, Rodrigo.  Recently I moved on with filling unrealistic values ```./tezos-client originate contract contract_oracle transferring 0 from alice running oracle.tz --init '(Pair (Pair (Pair 0 "1970-01-01T03:41:46Z") (Pair 0 "1970-01-01T03:41:46Z")) "tz1Z99RkyVoeRo8Xo15VkBpsNNcRSTsJ7Pzk")' --burn-cap 0.2```.  As both the None and Some "foo" format failed.  May come back later on the detail as I still feel a bit uncomfortable with the way dealing with this case.